# Java gui that allows user to move fields

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, mouse-listeners

I'm trying to create a java gui, currently I'm playing around in the netbeans IDE using their gui creator, but I've also been reading a book about Swing and trying to learn it that way as well. Im hoping someone can help me with a problem I'm having. I'm attempting to allow users to have a "pool" of fields they can choose from (for instance a title, a paragraph, a text fiend, buttons, etc) and be able to move items from the pool into another potion of the window which would let them create their own layout. At this point I don't need these fields to DO anything, but I do want the user to be able to move them around and create their own layout. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: *"I'm attempting to allow users to .. create their own layout."*  Work with `null` layouts or 'drop it wherever you like layout' for a while and you will see the impracticality of doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that to do this, you'd need to use a null layout on the container that would hold the movable components, and you'd have to give the components MouseListeners and MouseMotionListeners (conveniently combined into MouseAdapters) that are active when the program is in the set-up state, but then inactive when the program's components have been all set.

Comment: Thank you! this is definitely helpful. Ill look into how to do this!

Comment: I disagree for the need of the `null` layout. Take a look at the [`DragLayout` from the tips4java website](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/)

Comment: @Robin: yours is a good recommendation. Please make it an answer so I can up-vote it!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`DragLayout` from the tips4java website](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/).